# Ignore a window with a certain title in bug.n?

Tags: windows, bug.n

I have a window with the title `Find` that I want to ignore in bug.n./

Is there a way to do that?  Cause it's just a dialog box (but apparently isn't); is there a way to fix it so that it just ignores window with that title?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, if you edit the configuration file and use WindowsKey-i with a window selected it will tell you the class and the title of the window among other things...

Then you can use that to add to the `Config_Rules` in `Config.ini` see: https://github.com/fuhsjr00/bug.n/blob/master/doc/Configuring_rules.md